# Marshalling Error: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role (...), no session or session was closed

Tags: web-services, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I`m using Eclipse RCP with EJB exposed like WebServices. My services beans looks like follows

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Author> listAll() {
    final Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery("from Author");
    final List<Author> authors = query.getResultList();
    return authors;
}
```

The two entityes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book implements Serializable {

@Id
private int id;

private String title;

private String summary;

private String isbn;

@Column(name = "published")
private Date publishingDate;

@Column(name = "created")
private Date createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated")
private Date modifiedAt;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "book_authors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Author> authors;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private int id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "middle_name")
private String middleName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "created")
private Date createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated")
private Date modifiedAt;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "book_authors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Book> books;
```

In my TestWSCLient i`m trying to do something like this

```
AuthorServiceBeanServiceLocator locator = new AuthorServiceBeanServiceLocator();

    AuthorServiceBean service = locator.getAuthorServiceBeanPort();

    Author[] authors = service.listAll();

    for(Author a : authors){
        System.out.println(a.getFirstName());
    }
```

and I`m getting this error

> {....//xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Marshalling Error: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ro.cgs.entities.Author.books, no session or session was closed

I`m mention that if I do not make the Many-To-Many relationship all works fine. Can anybody tell me what should I do to fix this problem ? 
I use Hibernate for persistence.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you obtaining the entiymanager?

Comment: I`m injecting it with @PersistenceContext annotation and this is configured in my META-INF/persistence.xml. All my other methods works fine but when I try to make this Many-To-Many relationship I`m getting this issue

Comment: Is the persistencecontexttyoe extended? PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED

Comment: No, what do this EXTENDED type means? should this be the problem? I`ll try to make this change and I will come with a review. Thanks

Comment: Now I`m getting this error: {....://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Marshalling Error: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: ro.cgs.entities.Author@e3075c3b -&gt; ro.cgs.entities.Book@1aed1be7 -&gt; ro.cgs.entities.Author@e3075c3b

Comment: The many-to-many relation shouldn't be on both sides

Comment: extended means extended scope - the persistencecontext lives longer than for a single transaction